# Auto calculated expiry date ( Add 1 year to a date) - Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey I want to add a year to a date. Basically what I want here is to calculate a expiry date for a membership. When someone get a membership the system should auto calculate the expiry date.

```
        id: Number,
        startTime: Date,
        endTime: Date, // Auto calculate this value( startTime + 1 year)
        fees: Number,
```

As an example if someone is getting a membership on `2021-05-13T10:33:11.071Z`. His membership expiration date should be `2022-05-13T10:33:11.071Z` (One year duration). Data type of `endDate` is `Date`. If it is a `Number` it would be easy. But I want this with `Date` data type. Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of moment.js
https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/

```
        let today = new Date();


        id: Number,
        startTime: today,
        endTime: moment(today).add(1, 'years');, // Auto calculate this value( startTime + 1year)
        fees: Number,
```